# Spring retry on Transacional method doesn't execute the same sequence of steps

Tags: spring, spring-retry

I would like to retry transactional service method when JpaOptimisticLockingFailureException occurs

When I annotate service method with @Retryable annotation

```
@Retryable(value = JpaOptimisticLockingFailureException.class, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 500, maxDelay = 1000))
Account create(AccountDtoCreate dto);
```

and the service method executes the following logic

```
@Transactional
public Account create(AccountDtoCreate dto) {
    Account account = mapper.map(dto, Account.class);

    Schema schema = schemaService.getByCode(dto.getSchemaCode());       
    account.getSchemas().add(schema);

    Customer customer = customerService.findOrCreate(dto.getCustomer());
    account.setCustomer(customer);

    Account savedAccount = repository.save(account);
    repository.flush();
    return savedAccount;
    }
}
```

I execute 2 requests at once (creating the situation where JpaOptimisticLockingFailureException occurs).

1st transaction is committed, second throws JpaOptimisticLockingFailureException and retries.

Retry attempt fails on insert of the customer instead of calling findOrCreate method, or even getByCode method

Is it possible to make it properly retryable?

Answer (score 0):

After investigation, it was the problem with the way I used @Transactional annotations. Create method never got rolled back properly.

Comment: It is recommended that you share your fix not just that you fixed it for others who may have made the same mistake.